# How to select all orders for which there is at least one bid cakephp 3.0?

Tags: cakephp, select, cakephp-3.0, query-builder

There are 2 table tables that are linked through a foreign key in a one-to-many relationship

table `orders`

[image]

and table `bids`

[image]

Need to select all orders to which there is at least one bid.
On SQL this query is not difficult to do

```
SELECT * , count(bids.order_id) AS count_bid    
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN bids ON bids.order_id = orders.id
GROUP BY orders.id
HAVING (count_bid > 0)
```

but need make using the cakephp 3.0 query builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As example:

```
$query = $this->Articles->find();
$query
  ->select(['count_bid' => $query->func()->count('Comments.id')])
  ->leftJoinWith('Comments')
  ->group(['Articles.id'])
  ->having(['count_bid >' => 0])
  ->enableAutoFields(true);
$results = $query->toArray();
```